# Auto populate binary column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_comm_hist_xfer (
        tb_comm_hist_xfer_id binary(16) NOT NULL,
        tb_old_customer_id int NOT NULL,
        tb_customer_id int NULL,
        date_entered datetime NOT NULL
    );
```

I want to make `tb_com_hist_xfer_id` column as auto populated column like `IDENTITY` property. But I can't use `IDENTITY` for binary types. What is the alternative for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_comm_hist_xfer (
        tb_comm_hist_xfer_id binary(50) default CONVERT(varbinary(50),NEWID()) NOT NULL,
        tb_old_customer_id int NOT NULL,
        tb_customer_id int NULL,
        date_entered datetime NOT NULL
    );
```

Comment: Since a `newid()` will comfortably fit inside a `binary(16)`, why did you feel the urge to change the column length?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I thought when we convert the newif() value into a binary value,it would take more size,so I chose 50.

Comment: If you're going to be doing any sort of lookup by that column, I'd suggest `newsequentialid()` rather than `newid()` so they're at least in some order. Especially true if you're going to cluster on that column.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't want to use `uniqueidentifier`?

```
CREATE TABLE tb_comm_hist_xfer (
        tb_comm_hist_xfer_id uniqueidentifier default newid() NOT NULL,
        tb_old_customer_id int NOT NULL,
        tb_customer_id int NULL,
        date_entered datetime NOT NULL
    );
GO

insert into tb_comm_hist_xfer (tb_old_customer_id, tb_customer_id, date_entered) values (1, 2, getdate())

select cast(tb_comm_hist_xfer_id as binary(16)), * from tb_comm_hist_xfer
```

Comment: @AnandPhadke it worked for me and i am stick to use binary(16)